# ValueError: x and y must be the same size for 2D nparray matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Xtr,Ytr = load_svmlight_file("a9a")
Xtst,Ytst = load_svmlight_file("a9a.t")


Xtr=Xtr.todense()
Xtst=Xtst.todense()

print (Xtr.shape, "", Ytr.shape)
```

The Output was

```
Xtr = (32561,123) 
Ytr = (32561,)
```

I want to plot this on a scatter graph . But I receive an error which says Xtr and Ytr are not of the same size . How do I make them same size .

Comment: You can plot the scatter graph for same sizes of X and Y. You have 123 values of X's. So basically you will need to plot 123 scatter plots in each of which you will have 32561 X points and 32561 Y points. For example, try plotting the first column of X's as `plt.scatter(Xtr[:,0], Ytr)` and it will give you a plot of 1st X-variable w.r.t Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which column of Xtr do you want to plot? It has 123 columns, so you'll have to choose only one of them.

Comment: all if possible

Comment: got it I chose as @Bazingaa said .Thanks you both